# How to install MSYS so that it recognizes non-MSYS binaries?

Tags: windows, bash, msys, msys2

I have noticed that my MSYS bash doesn't "know" about the environment variables defined on my system. This means that if the folder `C:\MyStuff\bin\` is in my path, and that folder contains `mycommand.exe`, then running `mycommand` in the MSYS terminal will return an error indicating that it could not be found.

How do I cleanly "integrate" MSYS with the rest of my system? Is that something to be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I cleanly "integrate" MSYS with the rest of my system?

I use `Cygwin` (which is similar to `msys` in the way it works) and selectively add parts of my Windows PATH to my bash PATH as follows:

I have a file (`.path_elements`) containing the directories I want in my bash path:

```
/home/DavidPostill/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/c/Windows/system32:
/c/Windows
```

Note: if you add lines to your `.path_elements` file they must be terminated by `:` (except for the last line).

I modified my `.bash.profile` file as follows:

```
#DCP 20151019 comment out the original code for setting PATH
# Set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/bin" ] ; then
#   PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
# fi

#DCP 20151019
# Build up the path using the directories in ~/.path_elements
unset PATH
while read line; do 
  PATH="${PATH}$line"; 
done < ~/.path_elements
```

...

```
#DCP 20151019
# Add current directory to path
export PATH=".:${PATH}"
```

Now in my `bash` shell:

```
$ echo $PATH
.:/home/DavidPostill/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows
$
```

You should be able to do something very similar in `msys`.